# Bigquery source traffic differs from GA4

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I have seen a lot of questions about this subject, but no answer on how to fix it.
Hopes someone has figured it out now.

Basically, Google ads doesn't show up properly as the source medium in the BigQuery Tables. Sessions that started with an event containing the GCLID parameter are not correctly populated with "google / cpc (source/medium)". They are are all null instead.

I have checked in GA4 and those sessions are being populated correctly.

Comment: The issue is the the Google ads data runs slower than the GA4 data export, so the campaign information is not available when the data is written out to BigQuery. You can try to patch this in later by grabbing the data from Google Ads or SA360 and looing up the GCLID to find the campaign this way. It's far from ideal.

Comment: @BenP well, if that is the only way to get gclid's correct info to BQ, thats what I will have to do them. Kinda downgrading from GA3...